# bot discord does not react with emojis

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm using this little code to make the bot react to messages, but the problem is that it doesn't work and I don't know how to solve this bug.

```
import discord
from discord.ext    import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("whatever_text_u_want_here")
 
 
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if(message.channel.id == "77777"):
        await bot.add_reaction(message, "")
 
 


bot.run("")
```

Comment: IDs in discord.py are integers, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs, [`discord.ext.commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot) doesn't have a method named `add_reaction()` defined.

You need to use [`discord.Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) in this context, in order to add `""` reaction to the message you have fetched.

So replace...

```py
await bot.add_reaction(message, "")
```

with...

```py
await message.add_reaction("")
```

## Complete Solution

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("whatever_text_u_want_here")
 
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if(message.channel.id == 77777):
        await message.add_reaction("")


bot.run("token here")
```

### Demonstration

[image: demonstration]

Comment: I don't know what reason it is but it still doesn't work

Comment: @PeliculasYSeries please check the answer again, the answer received edits very recently, also thanks to `@Łukasz Kwieciński` for pointing out that `message.channel.id` is an integer.